# how to implement subquery in zend framework model

Tags: zend-framework

Hi I am new to zend framework

This is my sql query

```
select * from cwi_company where manage=1 and deleteOption='0' and passwordStatus=1 and organizationuserid in (SELECT userId FROM cwi_passtable WHERE passwordAciveStatus ='1';
```

I want to implement above query in zend model

Example:

```
$row = $select_company_table->fetchAll(
                                $select_company_table->select()
                                                    ->where('manage=1 and status=0')
                                                    ->order('id DESC')
                                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this using Zend_Db_Expr [Adding Expression Columns](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.columns-expr).

In your query the selct query will be

```
$select = $select_company_table->select()
                                ->where('manage=1 and status=0')
                                ->where ( 'organizationuserid IN ?' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SELECT userId FROM cwi_passtable WHERE passwordAciveStatus = 1'))
                                ->order('id DESC');

$row =  select_company_table->fetchAll($select);
```